# Matching some values from a list with values from a column

Tags: python, excel, list, openpyxl

I have the following issue:

I have to columns:

[image]

I have to create a list for each element from the first column. Precisely, I have to create  the following lists:
the first list for element 1 should contain [a, g]
for element 2: [r, t], etc.

I tried something, but I something must not be correct

The first part of the code I used to find out which elements are duplicated in the first column

```
    values = []
for i in range(2, ws11.max_row+1):
    if ws11.cell(row=i, column=1).value in values:
        pass
    else:
        values.append(ws11.cell(row=i, column=1).value)
print(values)
```

For the second part I wrote the following code:

```
listanew = []
for i in range(1, len(values)+1):
    for j in range(2, ws11.max_row+1):
        if ws11.cell(row=j, column=1).column == values[i-1]:
            listanew.append(ws11.cell(row=j, column=2).value)
print(listanew)
```

When I tried to print my new list, I obtained an empty list.
Could you give me a solution?

Comment: do you want a solution from your sample with loops to understant your error or with dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty to give names to the two columns; "A" and "B". Here is what you can do to group the data by column "A" and get a list of all the elements in "B":

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,2,3,4,1],
                   'B': ['a', 'r', 'fg', 'h', 't', 'd', 'd', 'g']})
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary (a `defaultdict` for shorter code):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d=defaultdict(list)
for row in range(1,ws11.max_row+1):
    d[ws11.cell(row,1).value].append(ws11.cell(row,2).value)

d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['a', 'g'], 2: ['r', 't'], 3: ['fg', 'd'], 4: ['h', 'd']})
```